# Evaluation of this complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve the equation for real numbers $x,y$, $(\frac{1+i}{1-i})^2+ \frac{1}{x+iy} = 1+i$

The suggested solution:

$\frac{1}{x+iy} = 1+i - (\frac{1+i}{1-i})^2 = 1 + i - (\frac{ (1+i)(1+i)}{1^2 + (-1)^2})^2$

Why does $(\frac{1+i}{1-i})^2 = (\frac{ (1+i)(1+i)}{1^2 + (-1)^2})^2$ ? I don't see how are they equal

Comment: Simply multiplying numerator and denominator of fraction by $(1+i)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Doug commented, simply multiply the numerator and denominator by $(1 + i)^2$.

The numerator is trivial to begin with ($(1+i)(1+i)^2$), however the denominator becomes:
$$(1-i)(1+i)^2 = 2i(1-i) = 2i + 2 = 2(i+1)$$

If we then plug this in, we see some cancellation and get the required form inside the bracket:

$$\frac{(1+i)(1+i)^2}{2(1+i)} = \frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{2} = \frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{(1)^2 +(-1)^2} $$